# How to extend USB beyond the recommended maximum cable length of 5m?

Tags: usb

I'm planning to use USB port for an application(from a device to a PC) but the distance between the device and the PC will be around 15m. The recommended maximum USB cable length is 5m.

How can I buffer the data without loosing any information, safely? Would a USB hub work?

Comment: Why not put a powered repeater midway?

Answer (score 10):

You can use a [USB over CAT5](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1725978&gclid=CjwKEAjwvPepBRCoqo37teOD1XsSJAC7v6WQrg7Ou8zkjqas8HKhr3ricXGoqgrNEIrmyEfKpp3JTBoCQcLw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) Extender.  The link is one example.  There are many available. You can then just add whatever length of CAT5 cable needed.  I have used one with a USB webcam and it worked perfectly.

[Alternate link](http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-2/USB-Extenders/1-Port-USB-over-Cat5-Cat6-Ethernet-Extender-up-to-131ft-40m~USB110EXT2) or search CAT5 USB extender and you will find something.  As noted, there are many models available

Comment: Please check also the USB capabilities. I have one which only does USB 1.0.

Comment: I got "Access Denied" error for your link. Maybe it's country-specific though...

Comment: @Ruslan  it works for me but you might be able to see it here. It's just a cat5(or cat6) usb extender http://web.archive.org/web/20151027031308/http://www.startech.com/ca/Cards-Adapters/USB-2/USB-Extenders/1-Port-USB-over-Cat5-Cat6-Ethernet-Extender-up-to-131ft-40m~USB110EXT2

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a hub would work.  If the hub is bus-powered, it will consume some power from the USB +5V, so the downstream circuit shouldn't draw more than 100mA (conservatively).

There are also [USB repeater cables](http://www.tripplite.com/usb-2.0-high-speed-active-extension-repeater-cable-a-male-female-20m-65-ft~U02620M/).

Comment: He's trying to go three USB lengths--you can't chain unpowered hubs.  At least one of them has to be a powered hub, or else use the repeater like you linked.

Comment: can you please explain what the difference is between upstream circuit and downstream circuit?

Comment: @barlop  It's only terminology.  Let's say that you've got a USB device (say, a keyboard, or a mouse), which is plugged into a USB hub.  The USB device is downstream of the hub.  The hub is upstream of the USB device.

Comment: @NickAlexeev  what if the device were an output device, like a screen?    Is the metaphorical river considered to be the computer, so the hub is upstream from the device, the computer is upstream of the hub and device, and the hub is upstream of the device? and the device isn't upstream of anything? the output device is downstream from everything.

Comment: @barlop  Yes, your understanding is correct.  The computer would the the source of the metaphorical river.  A screen connected through USB would be just another USB device.  (Sometimes, monitors have built-in hubs.  You could treat them separately from the screen itself, apply the same thinking.)

Comment: A USB repeater "cable" (aka active extension) is actually a cable with a dedicated, bus-powered hub with just one downstream port.

Answer (score 5):

Here are 6 ways to extend a USB cable:

1. Using a USB passive extension cable or passive hub
2. Using a USB active extension cable or active hub
3. Using a USB extender (over Cat5 Ethernet)
4. USB server
5. Using a USB over IP Converter
6. Using wireless USB

Details/Reference:

- [4 ways to extend a USB cable](http://www.wikihow.com/Extend-USB-Cable)
- [3 Easy Ways to Extend USB Cable](https://sewelldirect.com/articles/ExtendUSB.aspx)
- [USB Server](https://www.virtualhere.com/usb_server_software)

Comment: It's probably better to say "Here are 6" rather than "There are 6". 'cos a 7th might come along.

Comment: @barlop updated :)