# Can I extend USB 1.1 device by 5 metres using USB 2.0/3.0 hub?

Tags: usb

I have an older USB 1.1 device which I need to have 5 metres from a computer. I know USB 1.1 cannot operate over a 5m cable but USB 2.0/3.0 can. So if get a USB 2.0/3.0 hub, will I be able to connect the USB 1.1 device to it and use it on the end of the 5m cable connecting the hub to the computer?

Comment: Active hubs typically amplify the signal. Passive hubs do not. Better quality cables and proper shielding can also help extend communication length. Generally speaking, a hub with its own power supply will do a better job and result in a connection usable over longer distances than a hub that pulls all of its power from its connector.

Comment: Finally, you must also consider that, if you need to reach 5m, USB is not the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum length of a USB Cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/906765/how-to-extend-usb-beyond-the-recommended-maximum-cable-length-of-5m

Comment: Thank you @music2myear. I'll look into active hubs and USBoE solutions. I did see those other questions but they didn't totally apply in my situation, as I was asking specifically about whether USB 1.1 will work when extended via an active USB 2 or 3 hub.

Comment: USB has always been backwards compatible. 1.1 signals work just fine over other version hubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. A USB 2.0 hub (or USB 2.0 "sub-hub" within a USB 3.0 hub) will continue to communicate with host using USB 2.0 High-Speed signaling rate. To communicate with FS and LS devices, all USB 2.0 hubs have built-in so-called TT - Transaction Translator(s). The TT has buffers to hold fast-coming data, and then translate the data at much slower LS/FS signaling rates on downstream ports, autonomously. To communicate with TT, USB host uses so-called "split transactions", a subset of general USB protocol, which can check for completion of slow transfers using very short high-speed packets that do not take much of upstream bandwidth, saving it for other USB transactions. This is the whole idea.