# gsky wireless usb adapter not working with usb extention cable

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, cable

I'm using gsky wireless usb adapter model: Gsky-link GS-27USB.

When I connected it to a 15 meters usb extention cable it's recognized by the computer but it doesn't find any network.
Without the usb extention cable it finds many with good signal.

The cable I have seem to have a repeater (on one end it's pretty thick like the repeaters I see on these cables: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=usb+repeater&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt-L7a2MjQAhWhA8AKHWHaBd4Q_AUICCgB&biw=1239&bih=627 )

Just as a test - I replaced the original usb cable that connects the device to the computer with a simple cable and it also works.

Edit (added): The extention cable works when connected to a regular, simple disk-on-key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The 15m cable might be the problem. The max allowed lenght for USB cables is 5 meters, a third of what you are using. That likely causes a voltage drop, which may cause [parts of] the wireless NIC not to function.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable

Comment: How can I know/test if there is a voltage drop? 10x! :)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a voltage drop and the USB adaptor isn't getting enough power. The solution would be to have a *powered* usb hub on the other end with the wireless adaptor.

If you wanted to see what the voltage/current was, and how your cable affects the power input to the adaptor you'd want a USB power meter of some flavour to check. I won't recommend any particular model, but there's quite a few generic models around for not much money for casual testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try a longer cable but without a repeater since the process of repeating the signal also takes power. Maybe the signal will be acceptable even without the repeater. I believe here it is a trade of between the power that will get to the USB device and the quality of the signal. It seems that with good signal you do not get enough power.

The USB cable basically 'steals' some power to provide a better signal by that repeater.