# Printer is few meters away from laptop docking station, how can I connect USB?

Tags: laptop, usb, printer

I would need perhaps 4-5m long USB cable to connect the laptop docking station to the printer at home. The USB cable is too short. Using Ethernet is not an option simply put. I can't move the laptop docking station closer to the printer or the printer closer to the docking station.

So my question is, how can I fix this problem? Isn't there a maximum length on USB cables (as per its standard) which means we can't have a 4-5m long cable working reliably?

Comment: USB 2 or 3/C? USB 2 with repeaters you can get anywhere [eBay example](https://www.ebay.co.uk/b/Usb-Extension-Cable-10m/44932/bn_7023507452)

Answer (score 0):

The USB 2 specification allows 16 feet (5 meters)

You are at the outer limit, but it may be worth trying.

The other option is a USB wireless Print Server. Use that to connect the printer to your network.

[USB Cable maximum length](https://www.audio-technica.com/en-us/support/audio-solutions-question-of-the-week-what-is-the-maximum-length-for-a-usb-cable/)

> The USB 2.0 specification limits the length of a cable between USB 2.0
> devices (full-speed or hi-speed) to 5 meters (or about 16 feet and 5 inches)

Also

[USB 2 lengrh](https://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable)

.
and

.

[USB 3](https://nerdtechy.com/usb-maximum-length)

> USB 3.0 and USB 3.1 connection types have the same rating, and it’s a
> bit of an oddball. In theory, there’s no actual “maximum.” However, if
> you go beyond 3 meters (about 10 feet), your signal will start to
> degrade. The longer you extend the cable, the lower the speed and the
> less power it will provide. This gives you a little bit of wiggle room
> if all you’re doing is sending a signal. For example, if you need to
> send a security camera feed, a 20-foot run is probably doable,
> assuming minimal interference. On the other hand, if that feed is a 4K
> camera with two-way audio, you might have an issue. And if that camera
> requires the USB cable for power, you’re definitely going to have
> trouble.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I had 5m powered able that work well.. However, why not stick a RPI on it and print over wifi?